# mongoose document this.save duplicate key _id error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've added a method to mongoose that updates a product based on the input from req.body (express).

I know it's a very cheap way, but this is for an MVP at first.

```
const product = new Schema({
        //stuff
        gift: {
            from: {type: Date, required: false},
            to: {type: Date, required: false},
            active: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false},
            index: false
        },
    },
    {
        minimize: false,
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'createdAt', updatedAt: 'updatedAt'}
    }
);

product.methods.updateAndSave = async function update(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
    await this.save();
};
```

Error gotten:

```
Promise {
  <rejected> { BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.products index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5ad5eab958dde52d2c395ee2') }
```

It confused me since there is no `_id_` field...

Data send:

```
{
    "gift": {
            "active": true,
            "to": "2018-07-01T21:59:59.000Z",
            "from": "2018-05-30T22:00:00.000Z"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to overwrite the "_id" which is unique field in mongoDB. you should try following. Inside "this" object that you are saving, put old _id as new _id so it keeps value even after you "overwrite it"

```
product.methods.updateAndSave = async function update(obj) {
Object.assign(this, obj);
await this.save();
};
//so in Object.assign(this, obj); you would put inside "this" your old _id as new _id
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll update the question with the data I'm sending

Comment: It seems like Mongo is trying to copy your _id(which should be unique) aswell from obj. So then you have 2 documents with same _id.

Comment: But there is no _id property in `obj`, how is that possible?

Comment: From [MozillaDev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) : _The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object._

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've now fixed it with `this.update({$set: obj})`.